# How to make the scale area clickable in noUiSlider to move the handle?

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

When we [add a scale/pips to the slider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/pips/), this new area is not clickable to change the position of the handle. As I'd like to use a thin track style, this can be a problem for the UX.

I tried to follow the idea of this [issue](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/545) which is about the handler, but this modified all the consistency of all elements in that case.

How to make this new area clickable to move the handle?

[image: The wished clickable area]

You can find the [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcarree/jn096qbw/2/).

The scale area has been added with:

```
pips: {
  mode: 'steps',
  density: 10
}
```

Comment: Can you share your noUISlider configuration?

Comment: @JulianSoro, I updated the question to add an example on JSFiddle and a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired result, you can alter the height of the element matching `.noUi-base` as well as `.noUi-connect`. In this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbcua2c8/4/), I added this CSS:

```
#slider .noUi-base {
  /* makes the clickable area larger for pips */
  height: 55px;
}

#slider .noUi-connect {
  /* shrinks child of prev style to its original height */
  height: 18px;
}
```

As a recommendation, you might want to make a different class for "clickablePips" which you would target by `.clickablePips .noUi-base { /*CSS rules...*/  }` etc. This way, the developer is declaring what the intention of this style is, instead of having the style rule affect all items matching the `#slider`.

Comment: This increases the size of the green bar when we use the [connect](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-Connect) option. I made an [example that illustrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/rcarree/mbcua2c8/3/).

Answer (score 0):

To make the area clickable you can set the style of the pip to pointer and listen to the click event, like so:

```
let values = testSlider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-value');
for(let val of values){
    val.pip = val.innerHTML;
    val.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    val.onclick = (e) => {
        testSlider.noUiSlider.set(val.pip);
    }
}
```

1. `let values = slider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-value');` - Selects all pip values inside the slider.
2. `for (let val of values)` - Loop over each pip
3. `val.style.cursor = 'pointer';` - Set each pip cursor to pointer
4. `val.pip = val.innerHTML;` - Save the value of the pip (0, 10,20...) in the HTML element itself
5. `val.onclick = (e) => {
       slider.noUiSlider.set(val.pip);
    }` - On click set the value of the slider to the clicked value.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rr_alves/pxhsprvk/)